# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'arrayRemove')

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a cloud function in firebase emulator and I am trying to update an array. However when the function runs, I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'arrayRemove')`. I'm not sure what is going wrong. My node version is 16.

This is my function code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
const storage = admin.storage();

exports.completeEventRegistration = functions.firestore
    .document("<path>")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

     // <ommitted>

      try {

        await db.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {

          // <omitted>   

          const fieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;

          transaction.update(committeeRef, {"countries": fieldValue.arrayRemove({
            "name": chosenCountry,
            "taken": false,
          })});


        });

      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error registering: ", error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "Error registering");
      }

    });
```

Comment: It's saying that `fieldValue` is undefined. Are you sure that `admin.firestore.FieldValue` exists when you are trying to set `fieldValue`?

Comment: @mykaf I just checked with this: `functions.logger.log(Object.keys(admin.firestore))`. It outputs an empty array. Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `fieldValue` as follows, with `require`:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const fieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;
```

Comment: It has been declared above the update operation

Comment: Not as shown in my answer, see the `require`.

Comment: I tried it the way shown in your answer as well. It still gives me the same error: `Error registering:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'arrayRemove')`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue thanks to [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1954#issuecomment-1293934696) GitHub issue.

Following is the fixed code:

```
const
   { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app'),
   { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

const IS_EMULATOR = ((typeof process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR === 'boolean' && process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR) || process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR === 'true');

initializeApp();
let firestore = getFirestore();

if (IS_EMULATOR) {
   firestore.settings({
     host: 'localhost',
     port: '<firestore emulator port>',
     ssl: false
   })
}
```

```
transaction.update(committeeRef, {"countries": FieldValue.arrayRemove({
  "name": chosenCountry,
  "taken": false
})});
```